# Why do Windows Forms / Swing frameworks favour inheritance instead of Composition?

Tags: c#, java, swing, forms

Today a professor of mine commented that he found it odd that while SWT's philosophy is one of making your own controls by composition, Swing seems to favour inheritance.

I have almost no contact with both frameworks, but from what I remember in C#'s Windows Forms one usually extends controls, just like Swing.

Being that generally people tend to prefer composition over inheritance, why didn't Swing/Windows Forms folks favour composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: A lot has changed in the 15-20 years those APIs have been around!  Rendering engines didn't have magic XML glue to bind screen objects against instances of any arbitrary concrete class "back in the day" ;)

Comment: Most Swing code I see uses extension by composition. I'm not sure where your prof is getting his data.

Comment: I myself have seen a lot of swing on the net with inheritance instead of composition -- mostly tutorials though. but windows forms really are used based almost solely by inheritance!

Answer (score 7):

`JComponent` exposes [a lot of functionality](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#method_summary). If `JComponent` was an interface and components were implemented with composition, simple components would need to have dozens of trivial method wrappers, e.g.

```
class MyComponent implements JComponent {
    JPanel panel;
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        return panel.contains(x, y);
    }
    ...
}
```

There's also an efficiency reason to prefer inheritance over composition -- overriding costs nothing (assuming no `super` call), while composition costs an extra `INVOKEVIRTUAL`. I don't know if this influenced the design of Swing, but it's a big concern for collection classes.

Answer (score 2):

The Swing Framework is actually designed in accordance with the Composite Design Pattern. Granted that there is a lot of inheritance in there, but you would usually compose your own forms using composition. That is, a form is a composition of intermediate level containers and controls.

Comment: "That is, a form is a composition of intermediate level containers and controls." Sure. But what I see usually is that when people want to create their own window (or whatever that is called in Swing), they'll inherit from a window class instead of using composition.

Comment: @devoured elysium That's true. But to create the form they would use composition. So it is a little bit of inheritance and a lot of composition.

Comment: @devoured, I think that's a case of people not realising that the tutorial they use isn't following best practice because it's favouring brevity.

Answer (score 1):

With Java, its a **lot** easier to end up using inheritance just because *everything* is virtual.  Need to fix a "feature" in JTable/JFrame?  Extend it, override the problem methods, and then use your Table/Frame everywhere instead.

I think with things like WPF, where data binding is a primary feature of the design, makes it a lot easier to do composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: What do you mean with "everything is *virtual*"?

Comment: in java, every method is implicitly virtual (can be overrriden).  In C#, you have to explicitly declare a method as `virtual`, and to override it, you explicitly declare it as an `override`.  In java, you can override anything you can see, and you can increase its visibility in a subclass (you can make protected methods public in a subclass!)

Comment: Note that you can't override a `final` method in Java, even if the base class itself is not `final`.

Comment: that's true @perp.  but in java you have to go out of your way (adding final) to *prevent* virtual.  C# is the opposite way, you have to go out of your way to *be* virtual.  And a very small percentage of the standard java runtime is marked final.

Answer (score 1):

In [Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-141807.html), Item 17, Bloch mentions that a class *designed* for inheritance "must 
document its self-use of overridable methods." A hallmark of this is the phrase *this implementation*. You'll see it in classes like `JTable` and `JInternalFrame`. It's one measure of inheritance by design in Swing.

Answer (score -2):

From C# 3.5, we have a concept called as Extension Methods which allows the concept of composition than inheritance.

In this process, we implement an extended functionality to an existing class just by adding an extension class which renders the new feature to the existing class.

You can refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for more details

Comment: I don't see the relevance to creating new WinForms Control classes. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Peter: This is not related to only windows forms classes. This can be applicable from our code also. You can extend any of the existing class by just adding a static class and then adding new method with the 1st argument as this so that the base object can be linked to. After you compile the code, you get the newly added method as a method of the base class itself. This is what composition states. hope i am right..

Comment: I know what extension methods are, and they're quite handy at times, but this question is about different approaches to creating new classes.

Comment: @Peter: Then i can only point to the use of partial classes only, other than that to my understanding C# does not have any other remarkable feature. If you know of any, please do let me know.